# What is a topological group on $ \mathbb{R}^n\ $

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

While working on another problem, I have to use the idea of the topological group on $ \mathbb{R}^n\ $.   The on-line definitions don’t help much because they just say something like “$ \mathbb{R}^n\  $is a topological group under addition,” without further explanation.

Addition of what?  What are the elements of the group? Will it be clear how they add?

Just to make it interesting, I have the same question concerning the topological group on $\ S^1 $.

Please keep it simple.  I am no expert.

Comment: Do you know what a group is?  Do you know what a topological space is?

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, $\mathbb{R}^n$ always has the Euclidean topology, and has component wise addition as its group operation. These together turn $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a topological group.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ usually means the vector space with the usual addition and scalar multiplication. And vector spaces are groups with their vector addition.

Comment: @PossumP  the circle can’t be a group under vector addition because the operation isn’t closed:  both $\pm 1$ are on the circle but $1-1$ isn’t.

Comment: @Jason - Please address these issues: So “addition” means vector addition? Then, how do we have  topological groups for objects that are not vector spaces (since otherwise they won’t generally be closed under addition)? Also, a vector space is just a group with scalar multiplication, so “addition” can have many meanings. Finally, since the circle lives in the plane, what tells us to jump to the complex numbers to define its topological group?  Would we do that for other subsets of the plane?

Comment: @Jason - All vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic. What does that say for their topological groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Addition of what? What are the elements of the group? Will it be clear how they add?

If $\mathbb R^n$ is the group, then elements of $\mathbb R^n$ are the elements of the group. If you have experience adding vectors then you can figure out how to add the elements of this group.

$S^1$ is a multiplicative group of complex numbers with absolute value 1. If you are familiar with the multiplication of complex numbers, particularly in exponential form, then this is also simple.

If you don't know what a topological space is then you will probably have a tough time understanding the "topological" part of it.

Comment: So “addition” means vector addition? Then, how do we have  topological groups for objects that are not vector spaces (since otherwise they won’t generally be closed under addition)? Also, a vector space is just a group with scalar multiplication, so “addition” can have many meanings. Finally, since the circle lives in the plane, what tells us to jump to the complex numbers to define its topological group?  Would we do that for other subsets of the plane?

Comment: All vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic.  What does that say for their topological groups?

Comment: Addition just means taking two elements of the group and performing the operation called addition, however it's defined in that context, to create another element of the group. Any group can be made into a topological group with a certain choice of topology, and such a group is not necessarily Abelian, which vector spaces are required to be (in their additive operation), so no, there are topological groups that are not vector spaces. (Consider reading about the definition of a topological vector space.)

Comment: The complex numbers give us a nice operation that, informally, makes the circle of radius 1 a group. If you can come up with another subset of the plane and associated operations that satisfy the definition of a topological group, then there's nothing preventing you from doing that. I figure the complex numbers of any other radius should be easy to achieve.

Comment: Especially for a geometric shape, X, it makes little sense to simply refer to “topological group on X.”  For example in the plane, that could refer to the real coefficients or the complex coefficients, and addition or maybe multiplication as the operation, and one topology or another.  Similarly, for the topology on the circle.  Writers should define what they are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I won't go through checking everything very carefully, but intuitively, the operation $+:\Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n$ is given in the usual way. Given a pair of vectors $v=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $(y_1,\ldots, y_n)=w$,
$$ +(v,w)=v+w.$$
We know (from algebra) that this defines an Abelian group structure on $\Bbb{R}^n$, but more is true. Indeed, it is easy to see that $+$ is continuous as a map $\Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n$. This is because $+$ is given componentwise by $(x_i,y_i)\mapsto (x_i+y_i)$, which is continuous (in fact smooth). We also need to check that the inversion map (sending a vector to its additive inverse) is continuous, but this is nothing but the antipodal map
$$ (x_1,\ldots, x_n)\mapsto (-x_1,\ldots,-x_n),$$
which is continuous.

As for the circle, we can view $S^1\subseteq \Bbb{C}^\times$ as a subgroup under multiplication. If we represent elements of $S^1$ as $e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$ it becomes clear that the group operation is given by $(e^{i\theta},e^{i\psi}) \mapsto e^{i\theta}e^{i\psi}=e^{i(\theta+\psi)}$. You can check that this is again continuous. The inversion map can be viewed as the restriction of complex conjugation to $S^1$. I.e. $z\mapsto \overline{z}$. This map is a linear transformation of $\Bbb{C}$ (regarded as an $\Bbb{R}-$vector space) and hence continuous. It restricts to a continuous map $S^1\to S^1$ given in angular representations by $e^{i\theta}\mapsto e^{-i\theta}$.